# Javascript countdown to get current interval time running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have countdown function using Javascript/jQuery.

```js
function countdownto(target, time, callback) {
    var finish = new Date(time);
    var s = 1000,
        m = s * 60,
        h = m * 60,
        d = h * 24;

    (function timer() {
        var now = new Date();
        var dist = finish - now;

        var days = Math.floor(dist / d),
            hours = Math.floor((dist % d) / h),
            minutes = Math.floor((dist % h) / m),
            seconds = Math.floor((dist % m) / s);

        var timestring = days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs ' + minutes + 'mins ' + seconds + 'seconds ';
        target.html(timestring)
        
        if (dist > 0) {
            setTimeout(timer, 1000);
        } else {
            callback()
        }
        
    })()

}

// 10 seconds into the future
var time = "08/02/2021 17:05:00";
var time2 = "08/02/2021 17:33:00";

// countdown function call
countdownto($('#countdown'), time, function(){
   console.log('tadaaa')
   
   countdownto($('#countdown2'), time2, function(){
     console.log('tadaaa')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>

<div id="countdown2"></div>
```

Now I need to add function interval second there to get the current interval time.

My question is: how to get interval time inside this function:

```
countdownto($('#countdown'), time, function(){
   console.log('tadaaa')

   alert(time); // <-- how to get interval time? Alert not appear, as I know here when the countdown finish.
   
   countdownto($('#countdown2'), time2, function(){
     console.log('tadaaa')
  })
})
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Hi. I updated my post

Comment: _"Alert not appear"_ - Cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/x7jomv6k/

Comment: Hi, how to get the interval time before it finish as my question above?

Comment: The callback is executed _after_ the countdown. Why would you expect it to be executed before that? And what would be the actual usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you already have the time as string inside your global `time` variable. If you want to pass it to the callback anyway, you have to pass it where the callback is invoked:

```js
function countdownto(target, time, callback) {
    var finish = new Date(time);
    var s = 1000,
        m = s * 60,
        h = m * 60,
        d = h * 24;

    (function timer() {
        var now = new Date();
        var dist = finish - now;

        var days = Math.floor(dist / d),
            hours = Math.floor((dist % d) / h),
            minutes = Math.floor((dist % h) / m),
            seconds = Math.floor((dist % m) / s);

        var timestring = days + 'days ' + hours + 'hrs ' + minutes + 'mins ' + seconds + 'seconds ';
        target.html(timestring)
        
        if (dist > 0) {
            setTimeout(timer, 1000);
        } else {
            callback(finish)
        }
        
    })()

}

// 10 seconds into the future
var time = "08/02/2021 17:05:00";
var time2 = "08/02/2021 17:33:00";

// countdown function call
countdownto($('#countdown'), time, function(time){
    console.log('tadaaa')

    alert(time); // <-- how to get interval time? Alert not appear, as I know here when the countdown finish.
   
    countdownto($('#countdown2'), time2, function(){
      console.log('tadaaa')
   })
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>

<div id="countdown2"></div>
```